# How to replicate openssl command decrypting cms file

Tags: go, encryption, openssl, pkcs#7

I have tried decrypting a CMS file in Go, but have been unable to do so. The command I'm using to decrypt it via openssl is `openssl cms -decrypt -inform DER -recip X -inkey Y`. This works nicely and the file is decrypted correctly. At the moment I'm using os/exec in Go to decrypt it using this same command, but I expect there is some library that could perform the same functionality. However I've been able to figure out how that's done.

I have tried using the pkcs7 to decrypt, but without success, though I suspect this package is the correct one. My current attempt:

```
pkey, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(privKeyLoc)

//decrypt attempt 1
pk_obj, _ := pkcs7.Parse(data)
_, err := pk_obj.DecryptUsingPSK(pkey)
//err = "pkcs7: content data is a decryptable data type"

//attempt 2
rs, _ := ssh.ParseRawPrivateKey(pkey)
crt, _ := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(pubKeyLoc, privKeyLoc)
x509cert, _ := x509.ParseCertificate(crt.Certificate[0])
_, err = pk_obj.Decrypt(x509cert, rs.(crypto.PrivateKey))
//err = "crypto/rsa: decryption error"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the [mozilla pkcs7 library](https://godoc.org/go.mozilla.org/pkcs7) has very limited support when it comes to key decryption and used 'rsa.DecryptPKCS1v15' no matter what the pkcs7 object key algorithm identifier was. My key was encrypted using id-RSAES-OAEP, for which 'rsa.DecryptOAEP' must be used. My solution was forking the library and updating the [Decrypt](https://godoc.org/go.mozilla.org/pkcs7#PKCS7.Decrypt) function to check which algorithm is used and using DecryptOAEP when applicable.